# Installing a Theme with the Gnome Tweak Tool?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, 17.04

I just installed ubuntu gnome 17.04.  I'm trying to install this theme:

https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1171688/

It says just extract the theme into the `.themes` folder and use the tweak tool to select the gtk and shell themes.

So here's what I have:

```
ole@mkIV:~$ pwd
/home/ole
ole@mkIV:~$ ls .themes
Gnome-OSX-2.6
```

I then reboot and attempt to find the new themes.  However they do not show up even though I have `User Themes` turned on under extensions.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder, called .themes in your home directory. This can be simply created by firing up your terminal, and then running

`mkdir .themes`

Now this is a hidden directory, to view this in Nautilus, you can press `Ctrl/⌘ + H`. Alternatively,you can place the extracted files in `/home/accountname/.themes/(Gnome-OSX-II-2-6)`; you can also place the extracted files in your `/usr/share/themes/` folder.

I had try install the theme,unzip the file,and place the files in .themes/

Logout and Login your system,open `gnome-tweak-tool` change GTK+.

[image: themes]

Comment: I got it somewhat working.  The top bar and the dialogs have changed but I don't get the same look that the author of the theme has in the screenshot - also the folder color in Nautilus is yellow, instead of blue as the author has in the screenshot.  I have GTK+ set to Gnome-II-2-6 and Shell Theme set to Gnome-OSX-Dark-Shell

Comment: I  installed other widget to change the folder color. like:`Numix-folder`.default color is yellow