# Completing a Gnome Theme Install?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, 17.04

I'm trying to install this theme so that it looks like the screenshot:
https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1171688/

I followed the authors instructions and now I have the following settings:

```
GTK+: Gnome-II-2-6
Shell: Gnome-OSX-Dark-Shell
```

However the dialogs don't have all three (Minification, maximization, and hide buttons) and I'm missing the launcher at the bottom.  Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Any idea how to get the rest of the theme working?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu gnome style, you have to set that up from dconf let  me look that up :)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. You have an earlier question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/919802/gnome-theme-install-launcher which should be deleted. Thanks.

Comment: Make that thrice... https://askubuntu.com/questions/919608/installing-a-theme-with-the-gnome-tweak-tool please delete 2 of these dups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to achieve that:

1. Please install `dconf-editor`:

   ```
   sudo apt install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Launch it and go to `org --> gnome --> desktop --> wm -->preferences --> button-layout`
3. Add this configuration to the text box at the bottom:

   ```
   menu:maximize,minimize,close
   ```
4. Please the image below to help you:

   [image]
5. PLEASE MAKE SURE ALL YOU SEE IN MINE IS HOW YOURS IS. Close and you should be good.

Comment: Hi - Thanks that got me part of the way there.  The icons for shown for the settings dialog, gnome launcher, etc. are still the same though.  Any idea how to get the launcher the theme shows at the bottom and the custom icons?

Comment: Please could you explain don't get you?