# Gnome theme install launcher

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm trying to install this theme so that it looks like the screenshot: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1171688/

The theme has a launcher at the bottom and custom icons to go with it.  When I install the themes I get different looking dialogs, but not the custom launcher nor the icons.  Any idea how to get these?  Also the folder color in the theme is blue, but for me they are still yellow ...

Comment: The icon theme and the launcher is separate things. They come only with a gnome theme. You need to install theme separately

Comment: You can see an answer below. You should be able to install the launcher. That one is plank. I've seen your other question about the icon. So I guess you could grab the latest icon `v8`.

Comment: @Ole if you feel a question has been mistakenly closed, the best thing to do is make a post on [meta] and explain why. Another useful thing is editing (as you did) to clarify the question. As soon as you edit, it gets put in a queue and other users get to vote on whether it should be reopened or remain closed. Your question had already received 2 out of 3 required reopen votes when I cast the last one.

Comment: Great thanks! - I'll edit away the comments - etc.  I just find in general that people are very quick to waive the duplicate wand without really looking into why the question was restructured to start with.   We all want to find simple / minimal scope answers quickly - and it would be great to see moderators look at that core goal first before intervening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your claim that

> > *The theme has a launcher at the bottom and custom icons to go with it.*

is wrong. GNOME theme include only the gtk themes. The screenshot may include some other programs which may not be part of the theme. For example, the background image also isn't part of the theme.

But if you want to have the icon theme and the launcher, you can follow the steps:

### Icon theme

Add the ppa `ppa:noobslab/macbuntu` and install the `macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7` package

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7
```

I've known from your [other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/919868/61218) that you're using Zesty, and you needed to use `yakkety` release on the ppa source file. So, in that case, you should be able to install `macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v8` icon instead.

### Launcher

The launcher is plank. Install it with this command

```
sudo apt-get install plank
```

Install the specific plank theme using this command

```
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-plank-theme-lts-v7
```

You should be able to use the icon theme and configure plank with the specific theme now.

(Same here too. You should be able to install `macbuntu-os-plank-theme-lts-v8` following the advice on your other answer. If you do so, you can have very identical configuration as the screenshot of the theme)

Comment: Great - Thanks @Anwar - That makes a lot more sense now.  I almost just gave on gnome and went back to Ubuntu.  The noobslab instructions are very good in general for ubuntu.

Comment: @Ole Glad that It helped. I was able to reproduce almost identical theme settings and was planning to include a screenshot. But since you're able to fix all the problems now, I think it isn't necessary now.

Comment: Thanks @Anwar - really appreciate your help with this.  I have installed all the noobslab stuff before, but decided to give gnome a try since Unity is going away and found that theme in a OMG ubuntu article.  Since I'm new to gnome I was a bit shocked, when the initial install of the theme only changed my dialogs :)